# Multiple forms with listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

Could somebody tell me how to write the code so that when the user clicks on a specific entry in the listbox, for example if they click the first name "Josh", it will then open up a new form where i can then add and edit details to that paticular person? I have looked all over this website and nothing seems to be on here.

Thanks

Josh.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Events of listBox like Click event ... perform action what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
     {
         string st= listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
          //pass this string to new  form as constructor 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event for the selection changed of your `listbox` , also

```
   public Class Person
{
   string name {get;set};
   int age {get;set};
   string hairColor {get;set}
     ///....etc

}
 Person p=new Person();

  private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

             p.name = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Cheers for the help guys. The project I am working on is a Record system where the user enters a musical artists name and the number of members which is then stored in a binary tree (the artist name). I then want the user to click on the paticular artist they have added and then a new form will come up where they can add albums to the artist. I have got this far but I want to be able to save the second form with a save button and then the 1st form will appear. If the user then clicked on the same artist again it would show the albums of that artist which i saving in a linkedlist.